# Hold Twitter script from loading until all other scripts have been processed

Tags: jquery, twitter

jQuery, Cufon, fonts, jQuery plugins, and JavaScript code, are at the top of a page. The Javascript code is all wrapped in a `document.ready()`. Two Twitter scripts, one the actual script and one the JSON, are at the beginning.

A problem that is going on is that I have found out that even placing the scripts at the bottom of the page, Twitter scripts delay all other scripts from running because they have been wrapped in a document.ready.

One solution to this I can see is taking the document.ready() off of the functions and moving them to the bottom of the page, before Twitter. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[defer="defer"](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/) ?

Answer (score 0):

If execution speed is not critical, you can try [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_settimeout.asp) to call the Twitter script.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout(callTwitterFunction, largeNumberEnoughForOtherScriptToFinishLoading)

});
```